# Servlet JSP não funciona

Tags: java, xml, java-ee, jsp, tomcat

Estou com o seguinte erro no eclipse ao rodar um servlet:

> HTTP Status 404 - /TesteJSP/

***web.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TesteJSP</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Home Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlet.Home</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Home Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

***servlet***

```java
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Home extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Home() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head></head><body>Teste</body></html>");
        out.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }

}
```

**Minha estrutura do projeto***
[image: Minha estrutura do projeto]

*Obs estou usando o tomcat 7*

Comment: Boa tarde.
Você configurou o TomCat certinho?? ele esta aparecendo na aba de servidores no eclipse?? se esta verifique se ele foi inicializado, geralmente esse erro da quando ele não ta inicializado 
espero ter ajudado

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 o tomcat está inicializando normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo indica que você precisa configurar o arquivo chamado web.xml para abrir uma página de boas vindas quando a url http://localhost:8080/TesteJSP/ for requisitada

altere seu arquivo e coloque como este exemplo

Exemplo

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Seu erro ocorre pois ele não encontra o index.html

Comment: veja se funciona e me avisa

Comment: Vlw, era exatamente isso que eu não estava me atentando.